# How i can develop this in android studio

Tags: android

I found this in html as counter.How can i develop this in android studio.purpose of counting many item and display in it[image: sample image is here]

Comment: Please provide more information what you want to do

Comment: like this counting how can design in android xml .is there any library?

Comment: in timepicker we choose hour and min in scrooling like that way

Answer (score 0):

Well , you can build a row of TextViews (each for every digit and than creat a function to set the values.

```java
TextView TextView0 = findViewById(R.id.tv0);
TextView TextView1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
TextView TextView2 = findViewById(R.id.tv2);
TextView TextView3 = findViewById(R.id.tv3);
TextView TextView4 = findViewById(R.id.tv4);

public void setCounter(int counterVal){

//Let's say you have 5 TextViews so 5 digits
//We count the TextViews from left to right

String sCounter =""+counterVal;
Int devider= Math.pow(10, sCounter.size());
Int[] counterArray;

for(int i =0 ; i < sCounter.size(); i++){
counterArray[i] = counterVal /devider;
counterVal = counterVal - (counterArray [i] * devider);
devider/10;
}


TextView0.setText(""+(counterArray [0]));
TextView1.setText(""+(counterArray [1]));
TextView2.setText(""+(counterArray [2]));
TextView3.setText(""+(counterArray [3]));
TextView4.setText(""+(counterArray [4]));
}
```

Is this what you look for?
You should implement a custom animation for switching digits.